# Are there any good instant message APIs for the Mac?

Tags: macos, instant-messaging

Just curious, if you were to build an instant message client for the Mac what existing API or service would you use to handle the transfer of messages from one user to another? I am looking for something that can be used in conjunction with objective-c and is compatible with other popular messaging services such as MSN, Yahoo, Aim, gtalk, etc. I don't want to host the service, but rather connect to existing services and use their "pipes".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many [Instant messenger protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_protocols) out there.

There is a good bet you could find a Java API for which protocol you would like to use like the [XMPP Java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html).

Or

for C or C++ you could use the [libpurple library](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple).

Comment: Thank you libpurple sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks a lot of informations, so it's rather hard to answer. Please add some details on your requirements. What protocols do you need, what functionality, what development language do you use?

As a start:

Adium has been released under the GPL, thus you can use the code in your own projects as long as the license fits your needs.

http://trac.adium.im/

Another option, if you don't want to implement multiple networks but prefer to use a single protocol where the server provides gateways to other networks you can also check out Jabber/XMPP libraries that are available for the mac.

http://www.google.de/search?q=jabber+library+mac&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I'm going to go with libpurple.